# Java check com port connection

Tags: java, rxtx

I am looking for a bit of efficient code that can assist me in monitoring if a com port is still open using the `RX/TX` libraries.

Lets say I have a hardware device that communicates to the PC using a virtual com port and that device can be plugged in and out at any time. I want to show a connection status on the pc.

I have tried this with something like a buffered reader below and it registered that the device gets disconnected but I have to re-open the port from scratch in another method.

I am looking from something short like `comPort.isOpen ()` or something?

```
// Set the value of is running
Start.isRunning = true;

// Check to see if the device is connected
while (Start.isRunning) {
    // Try to connect to the device
    try {
        // Create a Buffered Reader
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(serialPort.getInputStream()));

        // Read the output
        if (Character.toString((char) reader.read()).equalsIgnoreCase(
            "^")) {
            // Set the connected flag
            Start.CONNECTED_FLAG = true;

            // Set the connected fag
            AddComponents.TFconnected.setText("Connected");
        }

        // Close the reader
        reader.close();

        // Let the thread sleep
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }

    // Catch a error if the device is disconnected
    catch (Exception err) {
        // Set the connected flag
        Start.CONNECTED_FLAG = false;
        // Set the connected fag
        AddComponents.TFconnected.setText("Disconnected");

        // Let the thread sleep
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*Disclaimer: Consider this a partial answer because I do not have intimate knowledge of the workings of serial ports, and my tests could not produce anything useful. Posting here regardless in the hopes any of this is helpful.*

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to receive any kind of "connection / disconnection" event messages. Sadly, as I am not intimately familiar with the workings of serial ports, I cannot give you a full and proper explanation. However, from [some research](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5002a113-c695-44f6-a66a-8a690f2d4cfa/serial-port-device-connected-event?forum=netfxbcl), one of the answers posted in that forum had this to say:

> There's no event by the system to inform you of [a disconnection event] because that would require exclusive use of the COM port.  If you have a SerialPort object created and have opened a port you should get a CDChanged when a devices is plugged in and unplugged from the serial port.  That assumes the device follows the pins standards; not all devices do.

Note that the poster, and the link I've provided, are discussing this within the context of C#. However this seems to be related to how the ports work in general, regardless of language, so I am somewhat confident the same can be applied to RXTX Java.

There are [some events](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/gnu/io/SerialPortEvent.html) you can attempt to listen for. In my tests I was only ever able to receive the `DATA_AVAILABLE` event, however my setup is a bit different (Raspberry PI) and I can't at the moment physically disconnect the device from the port, I can only attempt to block the device file (which may explain the failure of my test).

If you would like to attempt the event listening yourself, have your class implement [`SerialPortListener`](http://users.frii.com/jarvi/rxtx/doc/gnu/io/SerialPortEventListener.html), register for the desired events, check the events in your `serialEvent` method. Here is an example:

```
public class YourClass implements SerialPortListener{
    private SerialPort serialPort;

    // ... serial port gets set up at some point ...

    public void registerEvents(){
        serialPort.addEventListener(this);

        // listen to all the events
        serialPort.notifyOnBreakInterrupt(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnCarrierDetect(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnCTS(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnDSR(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnFramingError(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnOutputEmpty(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnOverrunError(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnParityError(true);
        serialPort.notifyOnRingIndicator(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Received event. Type: " + event.getEventType() + ", old value: " + event.getOldValue() + ", new value: " + event.getNewValue());
    }
}
```

If that ultimately fails, I believe the only other alternative is similar to your current solution; attempt to read from the port, and if it fails, consider it disconnected, and set your indicator accordingly. At each iteration, if it is disconnected, attempt to reconnect; if reconnect succeeds, reset your indicator to "connected".

Sorry I cannot be of more assistance. Hopefully some of that may lead to something useful.

**Side Note:**

If you want to DRY up your code slightly, put the `Thread.sleep(500)` in a finally block instead, since it appears to be executed regardless.